# How can I use an array within a method that was called in as a parameter for a different constructor initializer?? (Java)

Tags: java, arrays, methods, parameters

How can I use an array within a method that was called in as a parameter for a different constructor initializer in the same class?

For example:

private static Initialize(int[] array)

private static void Display()

I want to take the array called in above in the Initialize method and use it in the Display method. I kept getting null reference pointer errors when I first tried it. Thank you for any help in advance!!

Comment: Show your code, and most important, show the entire stack trace of your exception and indicate the line of code where that exception occurred.  You should edit your question to include this information using the “edit” link below the shaded keyword rectangles under your question.

Answer (score 0):

You can declare your array outside the method `Initialize` to have access in your class body.

For example:

```
private static int[] array;

private static Initialize() {
    array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3 };
}

private static void Display() {
    for (int i : array) {
      System.out.println(i);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assign the array to a class variable when `Initialize()` is called.

```
private static int[] array;

private static Initialize(int[] array) {
     this.array=array;
}
```

The array can then be referenced as `array` as long as Initialize has already been called.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mean how you can transfer one instance of array between classes.
Simplest way is using simple composition(in this case for one Array, but you can use it on n number of object):
First you need to define new class, which constructor takes in the array data as parameter and define the uninitialized array(which serves as a bridge between classes and also a container for the instantiated data).

```
public class TransferArray {        
    private String[] transferredArray;
      public TransferArray(String[] originalArray){
      transferredArray = originalArray;
      }
      String[] getArray() {
      return transferredArray;
      }
}
```

now to test this work, use this in the main class(both arrays now printing Hello)

```
String[] originalArray = {"Hello"};
TransferArray transfer = new TransferArray(originalArray);
String[] newArray = transfer.getArray();
System.out.println(originalArray[0]);
System.out.println(newArray[0]);
```